# Will auto vacuum analyzer delay visibility of bulk insertion or updation

Tags: postgresql

I am reading records from table A and doing some calculations and inserting and updating the table B. I am doing yearly migration from 2017 to now. For2017-2019 I am using different query(Function  A) and 2020 jan to now different query(Function  B). My migration has started at 9:57 and all the migration are over by 16:37. I am looping the year and months through service. Both the function s returning true to the service and I couldn’t find and bugs in postgres logs as well.But there are no inserted records in the table B. But auto-vacuum analyzer is running even more than 12 hours after the migration over which is showing background started time as  9:58 which is my migration started time. Someone please advise me what could be the reason and how can I solve it. Since I am new bee to the postgres and I am a software engineer not a DBA not sure how can I solve.

Comment: The visibility of newly inserted rows does not depend at all on autovacuum. Some typical reasons why new rows are not found are forgetting to commit the transaction that inserted them, or looking at the wrong table (wrong schema/wrong database).

Comment: Thank you for response. But It’s working with single instance I mean with less number of records. In the postgres log there is a warning saying consider increasing max_wal_size and checkpoints are reached so frequently. But I need some support upto which level it can go , what is the percentage of RAM we can allocate max and what else will be get effected..ect. Need a guide line on it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason is synchronous commit. Postgres has introduced this to increase the performance. The client gets results before actually it got committed. That’s why table did not get updated , getting time to update. I was checking before it get updated 
Source: https://www.mydatahack.com/top-10-configuration-parameters-to-tune-postgresql-for-better-performance/